# SSL is not in use on MySQL server

Tags: server, mysql, ssl

I installed MySQL server and I want to allow SSL support.

I added these lines to `my.cnf`

```
[client]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/client-key.pem

[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

I created certificates

```
openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 2048;
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 1000 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem;
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 1000 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem;
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 1000 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem;
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 1000 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem -out client-req.pem;
openssl x509 -req -in client-req.pem -days 1000 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out client-cert.pem;
```

I changed chown to mysql for *.pem certicates

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1407 Mar 10 13:00 ca-cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1675 Mar 10 12:50 ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1277 Mar 10 14:29 client-cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1704 Mar 10 14:29 client-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1045 Mar 10 14:29 client-req.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1277 Mar 10 14:28 server-cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1708 Mar 10 14:28 server-key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1045 Mar 10 14:28 server-req.pem
```

then I restarted MySQL server and I logged to service like root and checked the status.
But it is still showing that ssl is not in use. What I did wrong?

Comment: Has your server ssl compiled in? `mysqld --ssl`

Comment: and also `mysql> show global variables like 'have_%ssl';`

Comment: @bersch Yeah, It is duplicate, this thread helped me!